# App update in AppStore. if I remove the availability in that region

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, app-store-connect

I have a new version that is available in the App Store for update by mistake.

But I want my clients to use the existing version,

can I downgrade the appstore available version? prevent download of new build? or if I remove the availability regions/remove from sale prevents the user to update the new version?

Comment: You can remove the app from sale and then no one can install or upgrade it. You need to submit a new build based on the old code

Comment: Existing users of an app can keep using the app even if you remove it from sale. Past downloaders of your app can even reinstall your app if it's removed from sale. They just have to go through their purchase history to download it if needed.